# "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" sql, visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am just learning c# and sql server. This question has been asked a couple of times but the solutions posted don't seem to help me. 
I have a table called "LoginInfo" that has a user's "email" and "pass".
In visual studio i have this method that checks a users login information

```
private boolean dbQueryLogin(string email, string password)
    {
       string com = "SELECT pass FROM LoginInfo WHERE email = XXXXX@yahoo.com";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(com, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

       return reader.GetString(0).Equals(password);
    }
```

This keeps on throwing the error "Additional information: The multi-part identifier "XXXX.edu" could not be bound."
The syntax looks right to me, is there anything i'm missing??

Comment: You meant to put the email address in quotes: `WHERE email = 'XXXXX@yahoo.com'`. However, a much, much better solution would be to use parameterized SQL.

Comment: Start using parameterized query, don't invite sql injection

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the error message:

> The multi-part identifier "XXXX.edu" could not be bound.

That strongly suggests that the problem isn't with identifying your table - it's with the bit that ends with "edu", which seems like to be an email address.

The *immediate* problem is that you've forgotten to quote a value. The *deeper* problem is that you should be using parameterized SQL anyway, to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), conversion problems and unreadable code. Given that the value you've given in the same code isn't the same as what's in the error message, I suspect you really have code like:

```
string sql = "SELECT pass FROM LoginInfo WHERE email = " + email;
```

Don't do that. Use parameterized SQL instead:

```
private boolean dbQueryLogin(string email, string password)
{
    string sql = "SELECT pass FROM LoginInfo WHERE email = @email";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // FIXME: What do you want to do if
                // there are no matches?
                reader.Read();
                return reader.GetString(0) == password;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This still isn't good code though:

- Don't store plain-text passwords in a database
- Handle the case where there are no results
- Don't build your own authentication system at all; use an existing one written by people with more experience in securing data

Comment: Nothing can be better than this answer.